# HTTP-GET request of Angular API call not working

Tags: angular, http, http-headers, http-get, http-caching

I'm using Angular Web-UI to control a backend application (serving on a localhost in my case) to perform some specific tasks, but it seems like the GET requests are being cached.

When i send the request independently using a browser window (or Postman), it will request the server (every time).

However, when the query is fired from Angular, it shows a 200 response status (browser > networks) but the server only sometimes recieves it.

**Original Code :**

```
this.http.get(`request_path`).subscribe((data: any) => {
    callback()
})
```

For imformation, the server will always run on same PC as the browser. Hostname will always be localhost in this case.

Thanks

Comment: Requests should only be cached if the remote server gives caching hints, are any cache headers present in the request when your open your developer tools and open the network tab?

Comment: I have verified that there are no headers from the server side. Is there any other aspect of angular http i'm missing?

Comment: According to [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#caching), requests are not cached by default, , you could try giving the get function an options object like `{ cache: false }` to see if somewhere the default caching setting has changed in your app

Comment: I tried adding {cache: false} but did not work. Should I use some other way to create a request? @Ferrybig